# Website rendering insanely off the mark in IE 8.0.6011.19088IC

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser

I've built [this website](http://cpe.org.au/) last week, which has worked perfectly across all browsers that I have (even optimized to render nicely on iPad, iPhone, etc).

My boss uses a particular version of Internet Explorer that always seems to break websites that I build, but only slightly.

This website gets destroyed in her IE:

[image]
[image]

I looked around and found a JavaScript library that I think is made for helping IE<9 render as IE9 would, which I've implemented like so:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://ie7-js.googlecode.com/svn/version/2.1(beta4)/IE9.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

But it doesn't seem to make a difference.

I've tested the website in multiple versions of IE 8.* and all of them are fine, it's just this specific version (and possibly versions close to it) that are going berserk.

Any help and suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing worth checking is that the browser is definitely rendering in IE8 mode - try pressing F12 to get the Developer Tools window up, then check that "Browser Mode" isn't set to IE7 or IE8 compatibility mode and that the "Document Mode" is set to IE8 standards.

Try adding the following line to the `<head>`:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge,chrome=1">
```

Comment: For the record, you can prevent this being an issue in future by specifying <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge,chrome=1"> in the head (ditch "chrome=1" if you don't want IE to render using Google Chrome frame, if installed).

Comment: This is almost certainly it, and adding that meta tag should fix it. You should edit your answer to include it.

Comment: @Conan This appears to have fixed my issue for now, but I can't be certain until my boss brings her laptop in to test, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'm surprised it's only happening in this one version of IE 8 and not more.  Perhaps the other browsers are more forgiving of the following HTML problems.

Your code has over 70 validation errors... some are serious like missing tags, open tags, improper nesting, tags out of place, etc...

[http://validator.w3.org/](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://www.cpe.org.au/&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0)

Go through and tackle each error one at a time, then once complete, you'll have much more consistent results across various platforms and browsers.

Comment: Probably not relevant to the issue at hand, but it's good advice anyways.

Comment: @thirtydot, I'll have to take your word for it since I don't have the same experience.  But with all the rendering problems, I'd want my HTML tags to be correctly placed before trying anything else.